# Flattening a Set of pairs of sets to one pair of sets

Tags: scala, flatten, for-comprehension

I have a `for-comprehension` with a generator from a `Set[MyType]`
This `MyType` has a `lazy val` variable called `factsPair` which returns a pair of sets:
(Set[MyFact], Set[MyFact]).

I wish to loop through all of them and unify the facts into one flattened pair (Set[MyFact], Set[MyFact]) as follows, however I am getting `No implicit view available ...` and `not enough arguments for flatten: implicit (asTraversable ...` errors. (I am a bit new to Scala so still trying to get used to the errors).

```
lazy val allFacts  =
(for {
  mytype <- mytypeList
} yield mytype.factsPair).flatten
```

What do I need to specify to flatten for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use `flatten` for this, because `flatten` on a collection returns a collection, and a tuple is not a collection.

You can, of course, just split, flatten, and join again:

```
val pairs = for {
  mytype <- mytypeList
} yield mytype.factsPair
val (first, second) = pairs.unzip
val allFacts = (first.flatten, second.flatten)
```

Comment: or: `val (first, second) = pairs.unzip`?

Comment: @dhg so I can actually just change the `flatten` to `unzip` in my solution? I already have a Set of pairs coming through the for-comprehension, so if I am understanding correctly unzip will combine them into one pair of sets?

Comment: @dhg I had forgetten about `unzip`. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

Scala flatten works on same types. You have a Seq[(Set[MyFact], Set[MyFact])], which can't be flattened.

I would recommend learning the `foldLeft` function, because it's very general and quite easy to use as soon as you get the hang of it:

```
lazy val allFacts = myTypeList.foldLeft((Set[MyFact](), Set[MyFact]())) {
  case (accumulator, next) =>
    val pairs1 = accumulator._1 ++ next.factsPair._1
    val pairs2 = accumulator._2 ++ next.factsPair._2
    (pairs1, pairs2)
}
```

The first parameter takes the initial element it will append the other elements to. We start with an empty `Tuple[Set[MyFact], Set[MyFact]]` initialized like this: `(Set[MyFact](), Set[MyFact]())`.

Next we have to specify the function that takes the accumulator and appends the next element to it and returns with the new accumulator that has the next element in it. Because of all the tuples, it doesn't look nice, but works.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer was a little bit more lengthy, but still good for me to understand what's going on.

Comment: @jbx It's not just lengthy, but it does the job in one pass, rather than multiple ones. That's usually the advantage of `foldLeft` is that you can write as much magic into the body as you would like :)

Answer (score 0):

A tuple isn't traverable, so you can't flatten over it.  You need to return something that can be iterated over, like a List, for example:

```
List((1,2), (3,4)).flatten          // bad
List(List(1,2), List(3,4)).flatten  // good
```

Comment: Thanks. I have `Set((Set(1,2),Set(3,4)), (Set(5,6),Set(7,8)))` and the result I want is `(Set(1,2,5,6), Set(3,4,7,8))`. I guess all the nesting was confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to offer a more algebraic view. What you have here can be nicely solved using [monoids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid). For each monoid there is a zero element and an operation to combine two elements into one.

In this case, sets for a monoid: the zero element is an empty set and the operation is a union. And if we have two monoids, their Cartesian product is also a monoid, where the operations are defined pairwise (see [examples on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid#Examples)).

Scalaz defines monoids for sets as well as tuples, so we don't need to do anything there. We'll just need a helper function that combines multiple monoid elements into one, which is implemented easily using folding:

```
def msum[A](ps: Iterable[A])(implicit m: Monoid[A]): A =
  ps.foldLeft(m.zero)(m.append(_, _))
```

(perhaps there already is such a function in Scala, I didn't find it). Using `msum` we can easily define

```
def pairs(ps: Iterable[MyType]): (Set[MyFact], Set[MyFact]) =
  msum(ps.map(_.factsPair))
```

using Scalaz's implicit monoids for tuples and sets.